# Java Reading mixed data into different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get a scanner to read from an external data file, letters and numbers and insert them into separate arrays. I need to separate the first two letters into different arrays, and each of the two numbers into separate arrays, and I am having some trouble doing this.

I have tried doing `Scanner.next` and `Scanner.nextLine` and parsing it but it doesn't seem to work, can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

The data file looks like this

```
FH45 36.266

MF18 46.967

MH29 33.309

MT95 36.983

MR30 23.1768

FF31 42.55

FF65 39.96

FT50 30.962

FR80 19.375

MH36 24.017

QF40 30

MQ40 30
```

Here is my Code so far, All I have is arrays and I want to separate the four different things into the four different arrays, I don't want to print out anything at all.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Height
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
   {
       Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("info.dat"));
       char Bone[] = new char[12];
       char Gender[] = new char[12];
       int Age[] = new int[12];
       double Length[] = new double[12];

   }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to give us the code you have so far, and be more specific than "doesn't seem to work"--are you getting an error, unexpected output, etc.?

Comment: All I have is the scanner and the arrays I want the data to go into, I don't know what I should do to split the data and get it into the arrays. Most of the time it wouldn't compile right, or it wouldn't put the correct information into the arrays.

Comment: Working or not, it's best to include whatever code you do have.  Ordinarily, people will not code things up for you and will usually down-vote you, but looking at the 5 answers below, it looks like your lucky day.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(scan.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.print("Letter is" +scan.next());
                System.out.println("Number is"+Double.parseDouble(scan.next()));    
            }
```

If you use `nextLine`() method after `next`() then it will return the number along with space between the letter and number.So use `trim()` method to remove the space or `next()` in place of `nextLine()`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld{
 public static void main(String []args) throws IOException{
    Scanner s = null;
    String str = "FH45 36.266\nMF18 46.967";
    ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Double> array2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    try {
        //uncomment this line for file
        //s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt")));
        s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str)));

        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String token = s.next();
            try{  
                double d = Double.parseDouble(token);
                array2.add(d);
            }  
            catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                array1.add(token);
            }  
        }
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }

        System.out.println("Printing Letter Array ");
        for(String out: array1){
            System.out.print(out+" ");
        }

        System.out.println("\nPrinting Numeric Array");
        for(Double out: array2){
            System.out.print(out+" ");
        }
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to print only the part containing the characters and the integers. In this case ,I think you can use the following approach:-

```
import java.util.*;
public class Demo
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   ArrayList<Integer> Int = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<Double> duble = new ArrayList<Double>();
   ArrayList<Character> FirstChar = new ArrayList<Character>();
   ArrayList<Character> SecondChar = new ArrayList<Character>();

   try
   {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath)));
    while(scan.hasNext())
    { 
      String str = scan.nextLine();
      FirstChar.add(str.charAt(0));
      SecondChar.add(str.charAt(1));
      Int.add(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(2,4)));
      duble.add(Double.parseDouble(str.substring(5)));
      scan.next();
    }

    for(Integer I:Int)
       System.out.print(I.intValue()+"\t");
    System.out.println();

    for(Double d:duble)
        System.out.print(d.doubleValue()+"\t");
    System.out.println();

    for(Character Char:FirstChar)
       System.out.print(Char.charValue()+"\t");
    System.out.println();

    for(Character Char:SecondChar)
       System.out.print(Char.charValue()+"\t");
    System.out.println();
   }
   catch(Exception e)  
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally{
     scan.close();
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

consider you read all file with `BufferedReader` and sotred it in `Array` or `ArrayList` as i did for mylines: hope following code will help you

```
void doMyJob(){
       String[] mylines=new String[]{ "FH45 36.266","MF18 46.967","MH29 33.309",
                                      "MT95 36.983","MR30 23.1768",
                                      "FF31 42.55","FF65 39.96",
                                      "FT50 30.962","FR80 19.375",
                                      "MH36 24.017","QF40 30",
                                      "MQ40 30"};
       ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<String> data2 = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(int i=0; i<mylines.length; i++){
           //for FIRST two letters
           data1.add(mylines[i].substring(0,2));
           //So on as you want..


           //for VALUES
           String[] raw = mylines[i].split("\\s");
           data2.add(raw[1]);
       }
       for(int i=0; i<mylines.length; i++){
           System.out.println(data1.get(i));
       }
       for(int i=0; i<mylines.length; i++){
           System.out.println(data2.get(i));
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example, use Scanner.nextLine() to read the entire line into a String object.

Next, use the String.charAt(n) method to read the first two characters into your first and second field:

```
String letter1 = lineStringFromFile.charAt(0);
String letter2 = lineStringFromFile.charAt(0);
```

Next, truncate the first two letters from the line read from the file:

```
listStringFromFile = lineStringFromFile.substring(2, lineStringFromFile.length());
```

Next, create a Scanner for the string:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(listStringFromFile);
```

Now, since the string contains your two numbers separated by a whitespace, you can read the next two numbers from the string trivially using the Scanner object.